# Xamarin -- Set zoom in AVCapture not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, avcapturedevice, avcapture

Hello I am trying to increase the zoom of the camera to its max level in my application.

However after setting the AvCapture to its max value it remains at its lowest zoom level on the screen. Below is my code.

```
void Initialize()
{

var videoDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DevicesWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Video);
var cameraPosition = (cameraOptions == CameraOptions.Front) ? AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front : AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back;
var device = videoDevices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Position == cameraPosition);            

device.LockForConfiguration(out error);
if (error == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Supports Preset");
    var test = device.RampingVideoZoom;
    var d = device.VideoZoomFactor;
    device.VideoZoomFactor = device.ActiveFormat.VideoMaxZoomFactor;
}
device.UnlockForConfiguration();

while(device.RampingVideoZoom == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Zooming camera"); //This line is never written
}

//See below for value this returns in Console
Console.WriteLine("Current Format");
Console.WriteLine(device.ActiveFormat);

}
```

> Current Format

```
<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x1c48049a0 'vide'/'420v' 1920x1080, { 3- 30 fps}, HRSI:4096x2304, fov:59.680, supports vis, max zoom:16.00 (upscales @1.94), AF System:2, ISO:22.0-704.0, SS:0.000005-0.333333>
```

This code does not affect the zoom of the camera AT ALL.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[videoMaxZoomFactor Definition](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice.format/1624635-videomaxzoomfactor)

> A maximum factor of 1.0 indicates that the format is not capable of zooming.

There is no mistake in your code.

As the Documentation said ,if `device.ActiveFormat.VideoMaxZoomFactor == 1` ,the zoom is not available.

You can debug the value of `device.ActiveFormat.VideoMaxZoomFactor` to see if it euqals to 1.

Comment: So if you look at the line under the "Current Format" it has a max zoom factor of 16

Comment: what's the value of `device.ActiveFormat.VideoMaxZoomFactor`